# Rest PHP Json Authentication

Tags: session, rest, state

How to build secure HTTP authentication in PHP using no cookie / session protocol. I know I can use HTTP digest but how can I implement it in my RESTFull backend and how does it exactly work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use token based auth.

1. Client: send username, password.
2. Server: send back a token.
3. Then auth with token.